# julia: is it possible to play multithreading

Tags: multithreading, julia

I'm working with Julia.

There is a networking library: ZeroMQ.

What I need is to create a julia project which can receive multi-zeroMQ-sockets. Here is a simple explanation:

```
s1 = Socket();
ZMQ.bind(s1, ip1:port1);
s2 = Socket();
ZMQ.bind(s2, ip2:port2);
s3 = Socket();
ZMQ.bind(s3, ip3:port3);
ZMQ.recv(s1, msg0, 0); // it's blocking
ZMQ.recv(s2, msg1, 0); // it's blocking
ZMQ.recv(s3, msg2, 0); // it's blocking
```

So here I have three blocking `recv`, meaning that I should have a new thread for each of them.

But I don't know how to play multithreading with Julia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need threads for this, you just need non-blocking I/O, which in Julia is how all I/O works, but it's exposed with a blocking API via tasks. So what you need to do is receive each message in its own task:

```
@sync begin
    @async ZMQ.recv(msg0, 0);
    @asycn ZMQ.recv(msg1, 0);
    @async ZMQ.recv(msg2, 0);
end
```

However, unless you are receiving from three different ZMQ sockets, this seems like a strange thing to do since you can only receive a single message on a socket anyway, and by making them async, you won't know which message is which. But assuming you're getting messages from different sources, this is how you do it.

Comment: in fact I have three different sockets.

Comment: So you mean I can use multi-threading + blocking to achieve my goal? thanks it works but I kind of want to use mono-threading + non-blocking.

Comment: Well, if "it's exposed with a blocking API", I think I have no choice. Thanks dude.

Comment: I dont get it. Because for me it looks like a multi-threading.

Comment: `@sync begin @async begin sleep(1) println("a") end @async begin println("b") end end`. It will print `b` then after 1 sec, print `a`. It looks like a multi threading.

Comment: You can think about it that way if you want to, but there is only one kernel thread under the hood, using non-blocking I/O. How? [Magic](http://img.pandawhale.com/112743-shia-labeouf-magic-gif-Imgur-S-Q38U.gif). But no, actually coroutines and libuv.

Comment: aha, I understand now. Thanks a lot and nice gif :D