# zeromq + julia: how to set a flag

Tags: zeromq, julia, nonblocking

I'm using Julia with the package [ZMQ](https://github.com/JuliaLang/ZMQ.jl).

I've succeeded in sending and receiving messages with the ZMQ pattern Dealer/Router.

Here is how I receive a message:

```
dataRecv = bytestring(ZMQ.recv(sockRouter))
```

But it's blocking. What I need is NON-BLOCKING.

In c++ with ZeroMQ, we can do this:

```
zmq_msg_recv(&message, socket, 0); // blocking
zmq_msg_recv(&message, socket, ZMQ_DONTWAIT); // non-blocking
```

In julia, I've found a key word: `ZMQ.ZMQ_DONTWAIT`, but I don't know how to use it. I've tried like this:

```
dataRecv = bytestring(ZMQ.recv(sockRouter, ZMQ.ZMQ_DONTWAIT))
```

But I got an error:

> 'recv' has no method matching recv(::Socket, ::Int64)

So is it impossible to use non-blocking mode in Julia?

**Issue 1)**

I've posed a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650690/julia-is-it-possible-to-play-multithreading).

If I'm right, the answer in this question is about multi-threading + blocking.

I know this could work but I prefer to use mono-threading + NON-blocking.

**Issue 2)**

@Chisholm  Thank you for giving me the [source of ZMQ.jl](http://github.com/JuliaLang/ZMQ.jl/blob/master/src/ZMQ.jl#L506).
But I've done a test like this:

```
dataRecv = bytestring(ZMQ.recv(sockRouter))
println("after recv")
```

If I execute the code above, it will block at `recv`.
In other words, it won't print "after recv" until I send it a message.

So I think it's totally a blocking mode.

Comment: If you take a look at the source (https://github.com/JuliaLang/ZMQ.jl/blob/master/src/ZMQ.jl#L506) you'll see that recv is already setting the flag  ZMQ_DONTWAIT.  That must not be you issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [julia: is it possible to play multithreading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650690/julia-is-it-possible-to-play-multithreading)

Comment: @Chisholm  But, when I do `dataRecv = bytestring(ZMQ.recv(sockRouter))`, it's blocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking over the code at `ZMQ.jl` it seems the blocking is caused by the `wait` after the `:zmq_msg_recv`, so here is another definition of `recv` called `pollrecv` which can be defined in the Main module (changing `ZMQ.jl` is unnecessary):

```
function pollrecv(socket::ZMQ.Socket,zmsg::Message)
    rc = -1
    while true
        rc = ccall((:zmq_msg_recv, ZMQ.zmq), Cint, (Ptr{Message}, Ptr{Void}, Cint),
                    &zmsg, socket.data, ZMQ.ZMQ_DONTWAIT)
        if rc == -1
            if !(ZMQ.zmq_errno() == Base.Libc.EAGAIN)
                throw(ZMQ.StateError(ZMQ.jl_zmq_error_str()))
            end
            return false
        else
            ZMQ.get_events(socket) != 0 && notify(socket)
            break
        end
    end
    return true
end
```

You can use this function in the following way:

```
msg = Message()
while !pollrecv(s1,msg)
    sleep(3)
    println("ZZzzzz...")
end
out = convert(IOStream,msg)
println(takebuf_string(out))
close(msg)
ZMQ.send(s1,"response important for next receive")
```

Of course, the `while` implements blocking using polling, and the `sleep` should be replaced with other processing.

Comment: `ZMQ.get_events(socket) != 0 && notify(socket)`  did you forget an `if` or something there?

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your code but it doesn't seem that it works.

Comment: `if` not forgotten, it is short-circuit logic shorthand - the post `&&` expression is evaluated only if the first expression is true.

Comment: how does the code fail? not compiling? it was working on my machine (otherwise would be hesitant to post it)

Comment: rechecked it, and it is working. ZMQ.jl version 0.3, julia 0.4.2, libzmq 3

Comment: OK. It's all because of `Base.Libc.EAGAIN not defined`. I deleted that `if` and it works now.

Comment: `Base.Libc.EAGAIN` is a constant (it is 11). Just replace it with 11. Though it should be defined (perhaps there is some upper/lowercase problem). It's best to leave the condition there with `ZMQ.zmq_errno() == 11`.

Comment: OK. I use 11 for now :D

Answer (score 0):

**Temporary answer:**

According to the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650690/julia-is-it-possible-to-play-multithreading):

> but it's exposed with a blocking API via tasks

I think we have no choice as there is only a blocking API.

If someone finds out how to use a non-blocking API immediately, please leave your answer and I will accept your answer. Thanks.